# JS local storage button coding

Tags: javascript, button, stack

hey i need help with creating a delete button for my "notes" so it will delete it from the screen and the localstorage (u will notice i tried to make a delBtn function but with no success) i would appreciate if someone could post a fix to mine and explain me where i went wrong.
My JS

```
const tableBody = document.getElementById("tableBody");
const taskInfo = document.getElementById("taskInfo");
const taskDate = document.getElementById("taskDate");
const taskTime = document.getElementById("taskTime");
const delBtn = document.getElementById("delBtn")

let x = new Task("this is a test", "2021-04-14", "03:19");
let y = new Task("this is a 2nd test", "2021-04-14", "03:19");
//x.add();
//y.add();
let taskList = [
  x, y, (new Task("this is a 3rd test", "2021-04-14", "03:19"))
];

if (localStorage.savedTaskList)
  taskList = JSON.parse(localStorage.savedTaskList);

displayTable();

function displayTable() {
  tableBody.innerHTML = "";
  for (let task of taskList) {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("class","taskZone");
    const divTaskInfo = document.createElement("div");
    divTaskInfo.setAttribute("class","taskInfo");
    const divTaskDate = document.createElement("div");
    divTaskDate.setAttribute("class","taskDate");
    const divTaskTime = document.createElement("div");
    divTaskTime.setAttribute("class","taskTime");
    const delBtn = document.createElement("span");
    delBtn.setAttribute("class","delBtn");
    divTaskInfo.innerText = task.taskInfo;
    divTaskDate.innerText = task.taskDate;
    divTaskTime.innerText = task.taskTime;
    div.append(divTaskInfo, divTaskDate, divTaskTime);
    tableBody.appendChild(div);
  }
}

delBtn.onclick = function delTask() {
  delBtn.parentNode.removeChild(taskZoneElmToDel)
}

function addTask() {
  if (taskInfo.value == '' || taskDate.value == '' || taskTime.value == '') {
    return alert(`Please fill all the fields.`);
  }else{newTask = new Task(taskInfo.value, taskDate.value, taskTime.value);
  taskList.push(newTask);
  localStorage.savedTaskList = JSON.stringify(taskList);
  displayTable();
}
}
```

Thats the Html part of it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Task Board</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="scaleable-wrapper" id="scaleable-wrapper">
        <div class="very-specific-design" id="very-specific-design">
            <header class="Title">
                My Task Board
            </header>
            <div id="Input">
                </br>
                </br>
                <form class="Form" id="formInfo">
                    <label for="taskInfo">Task Info:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="taskInfo" name="taskInfo" required autofocus></input></br>
                    <label for="taskDate">Task Date:</label>
                    <input type="date" id="taskDate" name="taskDate" required></input></br>
                    <label for="taskTime">Task Time:</label>
                    <input type="time" id="taskTime" name="taskTime" required></input></br>
                    <input type="submit" id="addTaskDiv" class="btn" value="Save" onclick="addTask()"></input>
                    <input type="reset" id="resetForm" class="btn"></input>
                </form>
                </br>
                </br>
            </div>
            <div class="outNotes"></div>
            <div class="tableBody">
                <table>
                    <tbody id="tableBody">
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="delBtn">x</input>
</body>
<script src="Task.js"></script>
<script src="script2.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: What is `taskZoneElmToDel`?

Comment: You only added the event listener to the original `delbtn`, not the ones that you add dynamically in `displayTable()`.

Comment: `displayTable()` isn't a class or object method, why are you using `this` inside it?

Comment: could you explain to me more? (im a beginner coder so dont understand much)